# how to pass data from Django to react without database

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, web

I am doing a dashboard app using Django and react. The user 's data is from Dynamics CRM API. I created a function in python to fetch all the info I need for the dashboard. What I want to do is to first fetch the data from Dynamics Api of a user at backend and then pass it to React component. Since the data from Dynamics Api is updating,I don't want to save the fetched data to my Django database. I know the REST api needs a database to function, but is there a way to pass data to React without using api?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Serializer class directly.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class YourSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   field1 = serializers.IntegerField()
   field2 = serializers.IntegerField()
```

and for the view

```
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .serializers import YourSerializer

class YourView(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        yourdata= [{"field1": 1, "field2": 2}, {"field1": 1, "field2": 3}]
        results = YourSerializer(yourdata, many=True).data
        return Response(results)
```